# Positioning of the CV picture

Tags: positioning, moderncv, cv

I have been using cv templates from overleaf. However, I want to move the personal information more to the left and so also resize a bit the picture and make it bigger.

The upper part of the pictures shows what the latex code does and the second one is what I want to achieve

[image: Pic]

This is the code

```
% personal data
\firstname{Thomas}
\familyname{Jalabert}
\title{Étudiant ingénieur en Informatique}                        
\address{3, rue Soutrane}{06560 Valbonne}   
\mobile{06.51.06.82.19}                   
%\phone{+33(0)4.76.24.10.36}       
\email{thom.jalabert@gmail.com} 
\extrainfo{21 ans - Permis B}
\photo[64pt][0pt]{pix2.png}
```

I have tried the examples from [Here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_of_Figures) but I was unsuccessful

Comment: Have you tried to increase the picture height changing the 64pt to higher numbers?

Comment: Please specify which template you are using.

Comment: @Simon Dispa   the name of the template is Thomas Jalabert's CV (French Student engineer in computer science)  or here is the link to it https://www.overleaf.com/project/6082b8ef567b9317eadfce51

Comment: Please allow sharing, now access is restricted.

Comment: @Excelsior as it for now that seems to solve the problem. I have increased the number, the photos has gotten larger and none of the other information have been effected. Let's see if stays consistent when I add the other cv content.

Answer (score 1):

With the current version 2.1.0 of `moderncv` you can get an bigger image simply by changing `64pt` to for example `100pt`:

```
\photo[100pt][0pt]{example-image-golden-upright}% <====================64pt
```

Change `100pt` for your needs ...

Then you get the resulting first page:

[image: resulting pdf]

The distance between photo and text is defined with `\separatorcolumnwidth`, so you can change it with for example:

```
\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{1cm}
```

Then you get the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting second pdf]

The disadvantage (perhaps) is that now also the distance between date and text is 1cm long too.

If you do not like this you can use the following patch to change only the distance between photo and text like:

```
\makeatletter % <======================================= possibility two
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}
  {\if@left%
    \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi}
  {\if@left%
    \hspace*{1cm}\fi}
  {}{failure}
\makeatother % <======================================== possibility two
```

with the resulting pdf:

[image: third pdf page]

You can test this with the following complete MWE (important code changings marked with `<=======`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic} % head 1 body 1 foot -
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

%\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{1cm} % <============= possibility one
\makeatletter % <======================================= possibility two
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}
  {\if@left%
    \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi}
  {\if@left%
    \hspace*{1cm}\fi}
  {}{failure}
\makeatother % <======================================== possibility two


% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[100pt][0pt]{example-image-golden-upright}% <====================64pt
\quote{Some quote}

\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description 
  no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description 
  line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore 
  normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation 
  when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{book1}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}


\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                        % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file


\clearpage
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper 
neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque 
arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi 
volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis 
tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat 
vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis 
ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque 
orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut 
odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. 
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per 
inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec 
tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt 
odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing 
sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla 
consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec 
velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus 
et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna 
libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, 
tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci 
lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam 
venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```